Prevent VS Code suggesting turning a function into a class
I have an issue with VS Code suggestion turning a function in JS into a class. It gives the following suggestion message:

This constructor function may be converted to a class declaration. ts(80002)


I do understand why the suggestion and highlighting are done as described in this SO question.
While it is just a suggestion it does not alter the code but the wrongly highlighted function annoys me. I have found a SO question on how to disable all suggestions.
I still want to know if there is an option to disable only this specific suggestion and the wrong highlighting instead of all.
How can only this specific highlighting fixed to show the color of functions instead of classes?
(Code for those that require all questions to have code in the question itself):
function init() {
  BUTTON_LABELS.forEach((label, index) => {
    const BUTTON = document.createElement('button');
    BUTTON.addEventListener('click', move);
    BUTTON.ariaLabel = label;
    BUTTON.dataset.id = index;
    BOARD.appendChild(BUTTON);
  })
}

function move() {
  if (!this.textContent.length) {
    this.textContent = PLAYERS[turn];
    saveMove(this.dataset.id);
  }
}


As an FYI: I don't have any plugin JS related installed on my machine but on this sample I do get the same behavior. It must be something VS internal.

How is function init at all relevant? its presence or absence makes no difference to VSCode suggesting move could be a class

@JaromandaX IMHO it is not relevant at all. But being a couple of years at SO, you and I know some of the reviewers. They down-vote and comment on questions with missing code even if the code is not relevant to the question at all. init() just contains the event listener that calls the function and is highlighted as such wrongly aswell.

Oh, sorry ... didn't see the move in init .. :p yeah, weird that - it seems as soon as you use this in a function, VSCode thinks you want a class. Never noticed that before.

For your information, some VS suggestions are bogus. And some are good. Why do you think you should fix something specific that is highlighted? It makes no sense. The development suggests that you have some ultimate goals. You need to explain your goal and ask for advice.

@tacoshy — “They down-vote and comment on questions with missing code even if the code is not relevant to the question at all.” Oh yes, I saw enough of this trash. However, people not presenting relevant code are no better. It's good that you provided the code. No, it is not reasonable. First of all, any non-constuctor function not using this is pointless, it could be converted either into a constructor or an arrow function. Are init and move related? If they are, they should be united into a constructor function or a class. Don't forget that class is nothing but syntactic sugar.

@tacoshy — also, you are using something from the outside scope, if any, such as BUTTON_LABELS, BUTTON, BOARD. This is already bad. You don't even show those objects. Where are they?

@Jaromanda X — “How is function init at all relevant?” That, too. Almost nothing is relevant. :-(

As to your question, I agree with you: I would also love to opt out some totally improper VS code suggestions. I even knew the developers who broke their code badly due to following some VS code suggestions in a blindfolded way.  However, they should better be opted out selectively. Anyway, this is not a programming question, this is a question on the tool usage.

@SergeyAKryukov all your comments are completely irrelevant to the question. The reason why the code is written as it is has nothing to do with the wrong highlighting of VS Code! "Anyway, this is not a programming question, this is a question on the tool usage." -> Then you should read the SO Guidelines - on-topic Questions: "3. software tools commonly used by programmers". I would state that VS Code is a software commonly used by programmers and as such it is an on-topic programming questions.

@tacoshy — Okay, thank you for pointing out the guidelines. But did you notice that I never said such questions should not be asked? Did you notice that I agree with the inquirer that it would be good to opt-out of some VS suggestions? So, what's wrong? I would suggest you to be more careful. Irrelevant comments? This statement is questionable. Besides, what makes you think all comments should be relevant to the question? No need to answer, this is a rhetorical question.

SO is not a discussion forum and comments are not a replacement for off-topic discussion either. Yes, I did notice that you part-wise agree with me. Nearly all of your comments have nothing to do with the actual question.  "* also, you are using something from the outside scope, if any, such as BUTTON_LABELS, BUTTON, BOARD. This is already bad. You don't even show those objects. Where are they?*" -> Just as an example, how is that relevant to VS Code Highlighting? Same when you try to explain why I should use a class. It's completely off-topic! https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment
